# Trigger an event when a function is called in a class

Tags: php, class, function, events

Is is possible in PHP to trigger an event whenever a function in a class is called, without adding it to every function in the class?

Example:

```
<?php
    class A {
        function xxx() {
            //this function will be called everytime I call another function in this class  
        }

        public static function b() {
            return 'Hello Stackoverflow!';
        }

        public static function c() {
            //I also want this function to trigger the event!
        }
    }

    echo A::b();
?>
```

Comment: You essentially want to perform [Aspect-oriented Programming](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aspect_oriented_programming). A general AOP solution might be a little (or very) heavy-weight for your current purposes, but [this article](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/aspect-oriented-programming-in-php/) talks about using [FLOW](http://flow.typo3.org/)'s AOP capabilities. Not sure if you just need this functionality once or in a million places, so this may be overkill for you. *shrug* Edit: Better yet, @Oswald's answer about Go! is probably the better framework of choice.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

AFAIK there are no native language constructs for this. If you need it for debugging purposes I would advice you to have deeper look into the xdebug extension especially [function traces](http://xdebug.org/docs/execution_trace) (awesome! :)

Another idea would be to implement [`__call()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.overloading.php#object.call) in your class and wrap all public methods. But this requires to change the code and has other side effects:

(simplified example)

```
class Test {

    protected $listeners;

    public function __construct() {
        $this->listeners = array();
    }

    private function a() {
        echo 'something';
    }

    private function b() {
        echo 'something else';
    }

    public function __call($fname, $args) {
        call_user_func_array(array($this, $fname), $args);
        foreach($this->listeners as $listener) {
            $listener->notify('fname was called');
        }
    }

    public function addListener(Listener $listener) {
        $this->listeners[]= $listener;
    }
}
```

.

```
 class Listener {

     public function notify($message) {
         echo $message;
     }

 }
```

Example:

```
 $t = new Test();
 $l = new Listener();
 $t->addListener($l);

 $t->a();
```

Comment: Awesome! This is exactly what I was looking for. And no. The meaning for this is not to debug. In my class I'm having my queries stored, and to avoid useless MySQL connections I wanted to add a require MySQL function to make sure the script is connected to the MySQL server when executing the query.

Comment: OK :) I have enhanced this a little bit. Now it can trigger events (as you told in your question)

Comment: So what this basiclly is: when a private function is called its redirected to __call() instead, but then call_user_func_array() will call the private method? @hek2mgl

Comment: yes exactly, if you try to call a non visible or non existing method of an object and it implements `__call()` it will be called. Note that I made the methods private, not protected to make sure, they cannot being calling from out of sub classes

Answer (score 3):

This is a classic task for aspect oriented programming (AOP). PHP has no native support for AOP, however, there are some frameworks that make AOP in PHP possible. One of these is the [GO! AOP PHP framework](https://github.com/goaop/framework/blob/master/README.md). You can also implement AOP using [runkit](http://php.net/manual/en/book.runkit.php).

Comment: +1 for the interesting link. Have heard a couple of times about AOP. But never really digged into it. Will have a look at your link (GO!)

Comment: Aspect oriented programming is not the instrument to solve this, because the DB connection is an innate dependency of the query, and not an aspect of it. Automatic logging of all queries executed were an aspect.

Answer (score 0):

You need for PHP SplObserver: [From PHP Doc](http://php.net/manual/en/class.splobserver.php)

Answer (score 0):

This is a classic task for dependency injection and lazy initialization! The dependency is the MySQL connection. As it first needs to be available when the first query is executed, it need not be initialized at "startup", but only then. This is called lazy initialization, and its implementation is extremly simple:

```
class DbStuff {
  private $__conn = NULL;

  protected function _getConn() {
    if ( is_null( $this->__conn ) {
      $this->__conn = ... ;  // init (MySQL) DB connection here
      // throw on errors!
    }
    return $this->__conn;
  }

  public function someQuery($arg1, $arg2) {
    $conn = $this->_getConn();
    // MySQL query here:
    ...
  }
}
```

All "refactoring" required is calling `$this->_getConn()` in every query method.

Aspect oriented programming is not the instrument to solve this, because the DB connection is an innate dependency of the query, and not an aspect of it. Automatic logging of all queries executed were an aspect.

A trigger built around PHP's `__call()` isn't a good choice either; aside from knocking out modern IDE's inspections - which are great to see quickly whether a module is fine - it would unnecessarily complicate tests: a protected `$this->_getWhatever()` can easily be overwritten in a test facade object - derived from the class to test - to return a mock object or whatever. With `__call()`, more code is needed for the same purpose, which induces the risk of errors in code which is only there for testing (and should be absolutely free of errors)