# Calling a function when any function from another class is called

Tags: php

I want to use this simple class:

```
class Debug
{
    function __construct( $caller )
    {
       file_put_contents( "out", print_r( $caller, true ) . PHP_EOL, FILE_APPEND );
    }

}
```

And have another class:

```
class SomeObject
{
    public function someFunction()
    {
        // calls the Debug constructor or function automatically
    }
}
```

Whenever someFunction or any other function from this class is executed, it should automatically execute Debug constructor or call a function from that class and I want to grab debug data from which function the debug class was called. How can I accomplish this?

Comment: This sounds like homework but have you tried making `Debug` a `static class` and using `__FUNCTION__`

Comment: @RST if I made Debug a static class, I would still have to write Debug::log()  in each of the 'SomeObject' functions, correct? I'm trying to figure out how to make the debug class trigger automatically, without writing any code inside the functions of SomeObject.

Comment: this may help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16922277/trigger-an-event-when-a-function-is-called-in-a-class if it does don't forget to upvote the answer given in that topic, if you can.